# Different pointer value before and after return

Tags: c, pointers

I have strange problem, i allocated memory using malloc and returned address of this newly allocated memory. But this address is different before and after return (inside and outside function).

Here is the code (care only about 3 last lines):

```
char* InfoFile_getValue(char* projectName, char* key)
{
    char* returnValue = NULL;

    char projectInfoPath[200];
    sprintf(projectInfoPath,"projects/%s/info.txt",projectName);

    FILE* fp = fopen(projectInfoPath,"r");

    if (fp != NULL) {
        char* ptr;
        size_t len = 0;
        char* lineFromFile = NULL;
        while(getline(&lineFromFile, &len, fp)!=-1)
        {
            if (strstr(lineFromFile,key))
            {
                ptr = lineFromFile + strlen(key);
                ptr = ptr + strspn(ptr, ": ");
                returnValue = malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);
                strcpy(returnValue,ptr);
                break;
            } 
        }
        free(lineFromFile);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    
    printf("Inside size: %d\n",sizeof(returnValue));
    printf("String address inside function %p\n", returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}
```

And then i call this function using:

```
char* baseString = InfoFile_getValue(projectName, "base");
printf("Outside size: %d\n",sizeof(baseString));
printf("String address outside function: %p\n",baseString);
printf("%s\n", baseString);
```

I comipled this using CC and below flags:

> `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types
> -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-discarded-qualifiers `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lpthread -lm

And it gives following results:

```
Inside size: 8
String address inside function 0x5567d9ff4540
Outside size: 8
String address outside function: 0xffffffffd9ff4540
Naruszenie ochrony pamięci (zrzut pamięci)
```

It looks like it cuts this address to 4 bytes and prefixes it with 0xff, but i have no idea why, i have never came across problem like that. Any suggestions will be helpfull.

Comment: `sizeof(returnValue)` = sizeof of the *pointer* , not what it points to. Just saying. Dunno if that was the intent, but that's what you got regardless.

Comment: Yes, i wanted to check size of the pointer to make sure it is 8 bytes here and there. Just to make sure.

Comment: Normally you only see something like this when the *caller* isn't properly prepared for the call. I.e., it as no proper prototype and assumes `int` return, which enthusiastic warning-sqelchers "fix" by hard-casting it away. In such a case, if `int` and `char*` are different sizes (typical for x64 platforms), only 32bit of the 64bit result are actually reaped; the remainder is carried from the msb of the phantom `int`. But I don't see such shenanigans here. With prototype this code looks proper. If what you claim is true this should repro with `InfoFile_getValue` mostly gutted. Is that true?

Comment: Thanks guys, all of you, you are so fast! Yes i missed proper prototype of function. InfoFile_getValue was in separate file and i forgot to include "infoFile.h". I need to finally learn to read warnings or to treat somehow implicit declaration warning as error. Thanks again, you are amazing!

Comment: Hmmm. You compiler should have told you that this is missing. If not, you need to turn up warning level: `-Wall -Wextra`. And of course you need to take care about the warnings.

Comment: Yes it gave me a warning, but i just didn't read it :/ Now i added -Werror-implicit-function-declaration and it should prevent this kind of errors in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to get a sign extension of the lower 32 bits of the address. Just a wild guess, but I think that the compiler saw `InfoFile_getValue` as a function returning an `int` while pointers are 64 bits long.

The rule is that a function has to be declared before it is used. If it is not, C assumes that it is declared as `int func()`, that is a function taking any parameters and returning an int. You should make sure that you have:

```
char* InfoFile_getValue(char* projectName, char* key);
```

**before** the function (maybe main) containing `char* baseString = InfoFile_getValue(projectName, "base");`

Comment: I hope I have multiple account to upload your answer. This kind of answer is why chatgpt can't replace stackoverflow yet

Answer (score 1):

That looks like sign extension, so this very much smells like a C90 implicit int bug. That is, the compiler thinks that the function returns `int` with the value 0xd9ff4540, which on a 32 bit system is most likely a negative 2's complement number. Then somehow it gets converted to 64 bit because of `%p` and you get sign extension.

Easiest way to solve it this bug *to stop using C90 already*, it's bloody 30 years old, broken and dangerous. Getting rid of implicit int alone is reason enough to port your code to standard C.

In case you *have* to use it, make sure that the function declaration and definition are identical and that the caller can see the function declaration. Then maximize compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Answer (score 1):

Your experiencing value-truncation and sign-extension due to an ill-prepared caller. I.e. the caller isn't aware of the actual function return type due to lack of proper prototype. This can be aggravating unless you keeping a close watch in C, especially when dealing with a code base that seems to work just fine on platforms where `int` and `void*` are the same size.

The simplest case to repro this is below, and documents what **must** be going on.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void *p = foo();
    printf("main: p = %p\n", p);
}
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *foo()
{
    static int x;
    void *p = &x;
    printf("foo: p = %p\n", p);
    return p;
}
```

Executing the above code after build for both x86 (where `int` and `void*` are the typically the same size) and x64 (where `int` is typically 32bit and `void` is 64bit) will expose both the problem and the subtlety of how you can miss this in this former case. Both *should* exhibit warnings similar to this (which you should be treating as errors anyway)

```
1>main.c(13): warning C4013: 'foo' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>main.c(13): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'void *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
```

The results of the run on both platforms (obviously the values here can vary on your system)

**x86**

```
foo: p = 00A38138
main: p = 00A38138
```

**x64**

```
foo: p = 00007FF7E7B0C160
main: p = FFFFFFFFE7B0C160
```

With that you can hopefully see how two things are critical:

1. Always ensure functions you're calling within your source are properly prototyped before their usage.
2. Always compile with warnings-as-errors to catch problems like this.

Probably the biggest thing to keep in the back of your head is, by not doing both items above, the code *still* appears to run fine on x86, and *still* compiles on x64. The former can lull you into a false sense of accomplishment, and the latter just further confirms that, making hunting down problems like this especially irritating. Let the compiler help you. Make sure (1) and (2) are in your routine.

Comment: Thanks man, that exactly what happened. I migrate from x86 to x64 and after that i faced this problem. Now i learned something new and added -Werror-implicit-function-declaration to prevent errors like that in future.